# java draughts AI (multithreaded)

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence

This is my first question here, if I did something wrong, tell me...

I'm currently making a draughts game in Java. In fact everything works except the AI.
The AI is at the moment single threaded, using minimax and alpha-beta pruning. This code works, I think, it's just very slow, I can only go 5 deep into my game tree.

1. I have a function that recieves my mainboard, a depth (starts at 0) and a maxdepth. At this maxdepth it stops, returns the player's value (-1,1 or 0) with the most pieces on the board and ends the recursive call.
2. If maxdepth isn't reached yet, I calculate all the possible moves, I execute them one by one, storing my changes to the mainboard in someway.
3. I also use alpha-beta pruning, e.g. when I found a move that can make the player win I don't bother about the next possible moves.
4. I calculate the next set of moves from that mainboard state recursively. I undo those changes (from point 2) when coming out of the recursive call. I store the values returned by those recursive calls and use minimax on those.

That's the situation, now I have some questions.
I'd like to go deeper into my game tree, thus I have to diminish the time it takes to calculate moves.

1. Is it normal that the values of the possible moves of the AI (e.g. the moves that the AI can choose between) are always 0? Or will this change if I can go deeper into the recursion? Since at this moment I can only go 5 deep (maxdepth) into my recursion because otherwise it takes way too long.
2. I don't know if it's usefull, but how I can convert this recursion into a multithreaded recursion. I think this can divide the working time by some value...

Can someone help me with this please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *1. Is it normal that the values of the possible moves of the AI (e.g. the moves that the AI can choose between) are always 0?*

Sounds strange to me. If the number of possible moves is 0, then that player can't play his turn. This shouldn't be very common, or have I misunderstood something?

If the value you're referring to represents the "score" of that move, then obviously "always 0" would indicate that all move are equally good, which obviously doesn't make a very good AI algorithm.

> *2. I don't know if it's usefull, but how I can convert this recursion into a multithreaded recursion. I think this can divide the working time by some value...*

I'm sure it would be very useful, especially considering that most machines have several cores these days.

What makes it complicated is your "try a move, record it, undo it, try next move" approach. This indicates that you're working with a **mutable** data structure, which makes it extremely complicated to paralellize the algorithm.

If I were you, I would let the bord / game state be represented by an **immutable** data structure. You could then let each recursive call be treated as a separate task, and use a pool of threads to process them. You would get close to maximum utilization of the CPU(s) and at the same time simplify the code considerably (by removing the whole restore-to-previous-state code).

Assuming you do indeed have several cores on your machine, this could potentially allow you to go deeper in the tree.

Comment: 1. The latter is case. I know the deeper I go into the tree the chance is that I can get 1 or -1 increases, but this takes time.
2. At first I copied the whole board todo/undo a move (immutable). I simply don't know how to separate those tasks correctly.

Comment: That's probably true. How many sub-choices do you typically have in each recursive call?

Comment: in the beginning, about 9 sub-choices. I can't go deeper, since it takes too long :(

Comment: In mid-game you'll have > 20 choices, a/b pruning will reduce it to, say, 10 on average. That means 10 cores will add only 1 level (ply) to your depth.

Comment: @notused: You said `2. At first I copied the whole board todo/undo a move (immutable)`. Simply making a deep copy of mutable data structure before every modification, doesn't turn it into a good immutable data structure.

Comment: I don't understand what you people mean. I simply have a class (MainBoard) which has come functions to calculate the moves of a certain player, do a move, etc... In there I have an array which represents the board, consisting of Pieces (another class). At first I deep copied the whole board, make my move, did recursive call, undid the move by using the unedited board. Now I keep track of my changes in some other way, which uses less space. Isn't the point of backtracking to do and undo? What's the key concept (about immutability, backtracking, ....) that I don't get here?

Comment: I don't think there's anything you don't get. As usual, there's a trade off between CPU/memory. By using an immutable structure and the *undo*-approach, you save a couple of bytes of memory, (since you reuse the same board) but waste a few CPU cycles (carrying out the undo). The problem with a mutable structure, is that you can't easily split the workload over several threads, since each thread messes with the same data. If you go with immutable structures, splitting the load over evenly over several threads will be as easy as encapsulating the recursive call in a task and put in on a queue.

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend reading this book:

[One Jump Ahead: Computer Perfection At Checkers](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387765751)

It will give you a deep history about computer AI in the game of Checkers and will probably given you some help with your evaluation function.

Instead of having an evaluation function that just gives 1/0/-1 for differing pieces, give a score of 100 for every regular piece and 200 for a king. Then give bonuses for piece structures. For instance, if my pieces form a safe structure that can't be captured, then I get a bonus. If my piece is all alone in the middle of the board, then I get a negative bonus. It is this richness of features for piece configurations that will allow your program to play well. The final score is the difference in the evaluation for both players.

Also, you shouldn't stop your search at a uniform depth. A quiescence search extends search until the board is "quiet". In the case of Checkers, this means that there are no forced captures on the board. If you don't do this, your program will play extremely poorly.

As others have suggested, transposition tables will do a great job of reducing the size of your search tree, although the program will run slightly slower. I would also recommend the history heuristic, which is easy to program and will greatly improve the ordering of moves in the tree. (Google history heuristic for more information on this.)

Finally, the representation of your board can make a big difference. Fast implementations of search do not make copies of the board each time a move is applied, instead they try to quickly modify the board to apply and undo moves.

Comment: I'll think about this. I'll try the different scoring system. I'll try to increase my search depth. I still don't know about transposition tables. About the last point: at the moment I don't copy the whole board, do the move, keep track of the changes and then undo the changes when necessary.

Answer (score 0):

(I assume by draughts you mean what we would call checkers here in the States.)

I'm not sure if I understand your scoring system inside the game tree.  Are you scoring by saying, "Position scores 1 point if player has more pieces than the opponent, -1 point is player has fewer pieces, 0 points if they have the same number of pieces?"

If so, then your algorithm might just be capture averse for the first five moves, or things are working out so that all captures are balanced.  I'm not deeply familiar with checkers, but it doesn't seem *impossible* that this is so for only five moves into the game.  And if it's only 5 *plies* (where a ply is one player's move, rather than a complete set of opposing moves) maybe its not unusual at all.

You might want to test this by feeding in a board position where you know absolutely the right answer, perhaps something with only two checkers on the board with one in a position to capture.

As a matter of general principle, though, the board evaluation function doesn't make a lot of sense-- it ignores the difference between a piece and a crowned piece, and it treats a three piece advantage the same as a one piece advantage.